# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list jquery dynamic data html

Tags: javascript

I came up with the error i have tried everything but couldn't find solution. Please help me this i added whole code. Everything work perfectly but on onlick function is giving me this error i dnt why if anyone can help he or she will be highl appreciated and also let me know about my approch and please help me to improve my code and approch. Thank you so much. Here is my full code:

```
  var valuestring = '<div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-danger closbuttonclass" onclick="ClosEditplace(' + countid + ')" type="button" id="btnclose"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<table class="table table-responsive" style="margin-top: 5%;">' +
                    '<tr><td>Company Name</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcompanyname" value="' + data.CompanyName + '" placeholder="Company Name" /></td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td>Position</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtposition" value="' + data.Position + '" placeholder="Position" /></td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td>City/Town</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtcitytown" value="" placeholder="City/Town" /></td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td>Description</td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + data.JobDescription + '" id="txtdescription" placeholder="Description" /></td></tr>' +
                    '<tr><td>Time Period</td><td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" checked /><span>I Currently work here</span><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Year</td></tr>' +
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + data.FkPrivacyID + '" id="txtprivacyidabout" />' +
                    '<div class="input-group-btn dropdownprivacyclass">' +
                    '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-white bg-white dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ' + data.PrivacyName + ' <span class="fa fa-caret-down"></span></button>' +
                    '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.UserPrivacylist.length; i++) {
                        var privacyid = data.UserPrivacylist[i].PostPrivacyId;
                        valuestring += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="GetPrivacyId(\"' + privacyid + '\")" >' + data.UserPrivacylist[i].PrivacyName + '</a></li>';
                    }
                    valuestring += '</ul>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</td>' +
                    '<td>' +
                    '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" onclick="SaveWorkPlace()" />' +
                    '<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="cancel" /></td>' +
                    '</tr>' +
                    '</table>';
```

Comment: Wrap the param in quotes. `onclick="GetPrivacyId(' + privacyid + ')` => `onclick="GetPrivacyId(\"' + privacyid + '\")`

Comment: Now came up with this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: mohammed, welcome to so... one of the biggest mistakes people make is not posting all of the code.. the syntax error is not here. post the FULL code because as far as i know no one here can read minds..

Comment: It's a very bad practice to use inline javascript and certainly the ´onclick´ is not jquery.

Comment: (1) The code posted doesn't produce the problem described.  (2) What does any of this have to do with jQuery or ASP.NET MVC?  (3) Please format the code and the question to be human-readable.  If it's not worth your own time, what makes you think it's worth anybody else's?  (4) Your deadlines are immaterial to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
for(var i = 0; i < data.UserPrivacylist.length; i++) {
var privacyid = data.UserPrivacylist[i].PostPrivacyId;
var valuestring = '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="GetPrivacyId(' + privacyid + ') => onclick="GetPrivacyId(\"' + privacyid + '\") >' + data.UserPrivacylist[i].PrivacyName + '</a></li>';
 }
```

Comment: gives me this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: can you make in jsfiddle

Comment: How to make it dear

Comment: go to jsfiidle.com and paste all your code includin html and css and javsacript. and share that link here again so that i can visit it and view whats wrong.It is like working demo online and so anyone can view it.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < data.UserPrivacylist.length; i++) {
                        var privacyid = data.UserPrivacylist[i].PostPrivacyId;
                        valuestring += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="GetPrivacyId( "' + privacyid + '" )" >' + data.UserPrivacylist[i].PrivacyName + '</a></li>';
                    }

Answer (score 0):

```
this might work:
 for (var i = 0; i < data.UserPrivacylist.length; i++) {
                    var privacyid = data.UserPrivacylist[i].PostPrivacyId;
                    valuestring += '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="GetPrivacyId( "' + privacyid + '" )" >' + data.UserPrivacylist[i].PrivacyName + '</a></li>';
                }
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Please review my whole code in question and suggest me something

Comment: please provide the fiddle so that we can clearly understand the problem